# Supporting networks different than Ethereum in Web3j

Tags: web3j, java

I'm currently developing Java app that interacts with various networks. I searched it in docs, but without an effect. I would like to know if Web3j supports any other network besides Ethereum like BSC, Polygon, Optimism, Gnosis etc. Is there chainID parameter like in ethers.js or web3.js?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Web3.js works with all EVM based chains other than Ethereum. Mainly with BSC and Polygon being most used.

Its not based on chainId but the RPC URL you provide during the creation of web3 object.